# How to access the image which is inside extjs grid column header using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, extjs4.1

I am using extjs 4 grid in my application and this is my code:

```
{
    flex: 1,
    sortable: true,
    text: "<span  ' title='#{adminManager.licenseDesc()}'>License ? <img class=\"tooltips\" src=\"#{request.contextPath}/images/help2.jpg  \" height=\"18\" width=\"18\"/></span>",
    id: "rg",
    renderer: renderStatus,
    dataIndex: 'license',
    field: {
        xtype: 'combo',
        itemId:'license',
        emptyText:'Select',
        editable: false, 
        id:'govtOfficial',
        autoSelect:true,
        allowBlank: false,
        width:50,
        queryMode: 'local',
        store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
            fields: [
                'value',  
                'text'
            ],
            data: [['true', 'Yes'], ['false', 'No']]  
        }),
        valueField: 'value',
        displayField: 'text'
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to implement the tooltip text using the demo showin in "http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/#demos" website.

I implemented the same in the other parts of the page like this

```
<img src="#{request.contextPath}/images/help2.jpg " class="tooltips" style="margin-left: 165px;" title="#{AdminManager.licenseDesc()}" height="18" width="18"/>
```

and I am able to the access the element based on the class="tooltips" and it is working fine. But I am not able to access the image which is in extjs grid column based on the below class selector.

```
jQuery('.tooltips').tooltipster({
                   animation: 'fade',
                   delay: 200,
                   theme: '.tooltipster-default',
                   touchDevices: true,
                   trigger: 'hover',
                   interactive: true
                });
```

I understood that extjs assigns ids at runtime. How to access the image inside the extjs grid?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant part of the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dom` property of ExtJS objects.
`$(MyComponent.dom).whatever();`